# PHP read more link should redirect to same page or a new page

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie to PHP and front-end coding. I have been working on a form which displays rows of messages. Sometimes these messages tends to be too long so I am using Read more link to limit the text display. The link gets displayed for every message but when I click on the link, I would want it to either display the whole message in the same page or onto a different page. Here is the part of the code which gets the link:

```
enter code here
//message.php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ...
    echo "<tr>";
    ...
    echo "<td>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
    //------- display text with read more link ------------
    $string = $row['msgText'];
    if (strlen($string) > 10) {
        // truncate string
        $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 10);
        // make sure it ends in a word...
        $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '))."... <a href='single.php'>More</a>"; 
    }
    echo "<td>" . $string . "</td>";
    .......
}
```

I want the whole text to be displayed in single.php page, so how do I pass reference to this page? Or how do I display in the same page (messages.php) atleast?
Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send in the message id into the links url and then re-query the database based on the id in the url.

For example:

```
<a href='single.php?message_id='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>'>More</a>
```

Then you can use `$_GET['message_id']` in your database query to pull out that single row and then display the message.

Does this make sense? You can read more about the [$_GET variable here:](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Thanks Dish_Rex, I did get what you said. But after some trial and error I decided to display the whole text in a modal dialog box in the same page. Since I was already querying the database to get the text I decided not to have another page to display which needs db access again!

Comment: Ah, nice solution. Better user experience too.